# A compling error when using xode4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I use [DCControls](https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCControls) which is an extended open source UIControll. I download an run it with `XCode 4`， I get the error as below:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/apple/Desktop/domesticcatsoftware-DCControls-722bb9c/../DCIntrospect/DCIntrospect/DCCrossHairView.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have searched the file `DCCrossHairView.m` which is indicated in the error message in this project. `No search result`. I want to know the possible reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're absolutely right. It seems that they had some files for testing (or whatever reason), they *did* delete the files but not the references. Just select the `DCIntrospect` group and delete it. It should build fine after that (just tried it and it works)

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! One pic worth hundreds of words.

Answer (score 1):

Even I download the sample app and found that some of the files are missing.In xcode go to DCIntrospect folder there you will find that some of the files are deleted, they are not present in project even your DCCrossHairView.Delete those files and it will work.